# mktemp failed to create via template

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, ubuntu

I setup a new AWS server using an existing AMI. It creates an Ubuntu server:

I type

```
ubuntu@ip-1-2-3-249:~$ mktemp
```

I get:

```
mktemp: failed to create file via template ‘/tmp/tmp.XXXXXXXXXX’: No such file or directory
```

So I type:

```
ubuntu@ip-1-2-3-249:~$ mkdir /tmp
```

and I get:

```
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/tmp’: File exists
```

Any reason for this?

Comment: What are the folder permissions for `/tmp`?  What groups does the current user belong to?

Comment: typing "stat -c %a /tmp" came back with "777" and when I typed "groups" I received "ubuntu adm dialout cdrom floppy sudo audio dip video plugdev netdev". Please let me know if I should be checking differently

Comment: Can you create a file in `/tmp` without `mktemp`?  Like `date > /tmp/test`?

Comment: I am getting the same and yes I can create a file like that @Mr.Llama

Comment: Any extended attributes? `lsattr -dlv /tmp`